# Experimenting with DOM functions

Tags: javascript, dom

Most of the experience I have manipulating HTML elements using Javascript involves the `innerHTML` property.  My knowledge is severely lacking when it comes to DOM manipulation.  So, to try and rectify this, I've been experimenting with Javascript DOM functions.

A simple test is to merely add a node to the DOM.  There are countless tutorials on the Internet which demonstrate how to do this, and yet for some reason I'm unable to get it to actually work.

In the following test code, I have an HTML `input` element that, when clicked, triggers a Javascript function that is supposed to simply add a `div` element to the DOM and make it appear on the screen.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function test()
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>blah blah</h1>";
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, document.getElementById('DOMTester'));
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<input id='DOMTester' type='submit' onclick='test()'>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, this doesn't work.  It generates an exception on Firefox when `insertBefore()` is called: `"Node was not found"  code: "8" nsresult: "0x80530008 (NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_FOUND_ERR)"`

Why does this fail?  Shouldn't this simply insert the new `div` element before the `submit` button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to insert the node into the `<body>`, but the `<body>` tag is not the parent of your input element. Try giving the `<div>` around the `<input>` an "id" value, and then do:

```
document.getElementById("theDiv").insertBefore(newDiv, document.getElementById('DOMTester'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler test:

```
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Your problem is that when you supply a reference element it must be a child of the element that is the receiver of the `insertBefore` method (in this case `document.body`). Do:

```
var tester = document.getElementById('DOMTester');
tester.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv,tester);
```

Comment: ... and it also insists that the element in whose context the function is called be the *parent* of the reference element (second parameter).

Comment: @Pointy Not only that, but the OP also got correct the order. I pretty much failed on the first pass at this answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var input = document.getElementById('DOMTester');

input.onclick = function() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = '<h1>blah blah</h1>';
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, this);
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/NwnKU/

Answer (score 0):

You need to take off the extra `div` surrounding the `input#DOMTester`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xycve/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function test()
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>blah blah</h1>";
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, document.getElementById('DOMTester'));
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id='DOMTester' type='submit' onclick='test()'>

</body>
</html>
```